# Spring Boot + Maven: Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM

Tags: java, spring, maven

Estoy creando un proyecto de Spring Boot usando el Spring Starter Project. En un principio lo hice con normalidad un par de veces hace unos días. Hoy lo vuelvo a intentar y encuentro con este error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La descripción del error es esta:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to transfer
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.15.RELEASE
>   from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.15.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed
>   out and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Hay preguntas similares que sugieren que haga esto:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.15.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Pero no pasa nada. Y en general no entiendo el error (a que se refiere). Por favor necesito que me echen algo de luz. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te dice el mensaje es que Maven fue a descargar una dependencia (en este caso el `parent` y no lo pudo encontrar).

Pudo ser por cualquier cosa puntual (fallo de conexión, servidor caído, etc.); la cuestión es que por defecto, Maven no reintenta descargar de nuevo las dependencias hasta pasado un tiempo, con lo que te sale lo mismo.

Opciones:

- Ejecutar maven con la opción `-U` que fuerza la actualización de dependencias.
- Buscar el repositorio local de maven (en `$HOME/.m2/repository`), encontrar la carpeta `org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent` y borrarla, para que no encuentre la dependencia en local y vuelva a intentar cargarla. Más trabajo, pero no intentará actualizarte TODAS las dependencias que tengas.

Answer (score 2):

Acabo de solucionar el problema gracias al comentario de arriba:
Si, deduzco que el problema es porque el servidor de MAVEN presenta algún fallo... ya que al crear el proyecto EL ARCHIVO PON se crea con la versión 2.2.2(EN MI CASO):

Versión que existe ya que no se descarga

Al dirigirnos a la siguiente ruta de nuestro equipo:

```
C:\Users\USUARIO\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter
```

Encontraremos las versiones disponibles....en mi caso encontré (2.1.8 - 2.2.0 - 2.2.1) como vemos no existe la versión 2.2.2 que aparece en el archivo PON de mi proyecto

La solución

- En el archivo PON cambié a la versión 2.2.1 (2.2.1.RELEASE)

Ya que es la mas reciente disponible en mi PC